# Как в Rust вывести в консоль любой тип данных?

Tags: rust

Есть какой-то аналог `var_dump` или что-то подобное?

Либо любой другой аналог для дебагинга и просмотра, что же я получаю в той или иной функции и т.д.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не совсем «любой», но почти: чтобы просто выводить для отладки произвольный тип, нужно сделать его наследником трейта [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html), после чего его можно с лёгкостью форматировать с помощью обычных функций и спецификатора `{:?}`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

let origin = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };

println!("The origin is: {:?}", origin); // => The origin is: Point { x: 0, y: 0 }
```

Для всех стандартных типов и почти для всех публичных библиотечных, для которых это имеет хоть какой-то смысл, данный трейт определён. Если же нет или если определение по умолчанию не устраивает, то можно сделать это вручную как-то так:

```
impl fmt::Debug for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Point {{ x: {}, y: {} }}", self.x, self.y)
    }
}
```

См. также: [Debug в Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_debug.html), [форматирование строк](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/).

Answer (score 9):

Можно использовать макро [`dbg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.dbg.html):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hash = HashMap::new();
    hash.insert("Test", "123");
    dbg!(hash);
}
```

[Выведется:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f2c0c8f2daab991ad021a7e47b481bba)

```
[src/main.rs:6] hash = {
    "Test": "123"
}
```

См. также [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39039723/93540).